# How to post audio and image as multipart/formdata in native android?

Tags: android, file-upload, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I want to post Form Data like this,

[image]

where,

1. ApiKey, userid, albumid, music_name, singer_name are the keys whose corresponding values are all text type.
2. music_cover and music_file are the keys for image file and audio file as their value.

> All the values are non nullable. That is, must pass all values to the
>   server to get a success response.

So, all in all, I have a bunch of texts and an audio and an image to upload to server using web service from android.

I am picking the image and audio using picker, so I have their file path.

Please guide me through the process of uploading audio and image using multipart from android.

It has kept me up all night and yet no reprieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created an example using Volley 
So first of all we have to build a `RestApiMultiPartRequests.class` so here i created it like this

private class RestApiMultiPartRequests extends Request {

```
private final Map<String, String> mStringParts;
private final Map<String, File> mFileParts;
private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder;
private final Response.Listener<T> mListener;

public RestApiMultiPartRequests(String url,
                                Map<String, String> stringParts,
                                Map<String, File> fileParts,
                                Response.Listener<T> listener,
                                Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
    mStringParts = stringParts;
    mFileParts = fileParts;
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    if (mBuilder != null) {
        mBuilder = null;
    }
    mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mBuilder.setBoundary("_____" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "_____");
    mBuilder.setCharset(Consts.UTF_8);
    if (mStringParts != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringParts.entrySet()) {
            mBuilder.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
    }

    Log.e("Size", "Size: " + mFileParts.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, File> entry : mFileParts.entrySet()) {
        ContentType imageContentType = ContentType.create("image/*");//MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
        Log.d("", "Key " + entry.getKey());
        Log.d("", "Value " + entry.getValue());
        Log.d("", "Name " + entry.getValue().getName());
        //"userfile"
        mBuilder.addBinaryBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), imageContentType, entry.getValue().getName());
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
}


public HttpEntity getEntity() {
    return mBuilder.build();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return (Response<T>) Response.success(jsonString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);

}


}
```

Using this class we can build a request like this

```
 private void UploadImage() {

    ServiceCall.RestApiMultiPartRequests<String> restApiMultiPartRequest =
            new ServiceCall.RestApiMultiPartRequests<String>(url/*YOUR SERVICE URL*/, hashMap /* HASHMAP OF STRING */, fileparts  /*HASH MAP OF FILE AND STRING */, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   /*   HANDEL YOUR SUCCESS RESPONSE **/
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No
                    // connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
                    // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user
                    // credentials.
                    // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on
                    // client side when sending api request.
                    // In this case you can check how client is forming the
                    // api and debug accordingly.
                    // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle
                    // accordingly.


                      /**  HANDLE YOUR ERRORS */
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization","YOUR AUTHANTICATION TOKEN IF REQUIRED");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return params;
                }
            };

    restApiMultiPartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 1, 2));//10000
    VOLLEY_INSTANCE.addToRequestQueue(restApiMultiPartRequest);
}
```

Here `hashmap` is  `HashMap<String, String> hashMap`
and `fileparts`   is `HashMap<String, File> fileparts;`

so the parameters with `String` `key` and `String` `value` add in to `hashmap` 
and parameters with `String` key and `File` `Value` add into `fileparts`

Comment: I am stuck with MultipartEntityBuilder. Unable to find it in the Android project. Why am I getting error in the related lines?

Comment: And what is the T in Response<T>??

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell you that for that you have to add library  

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

add like this 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: dependencies {
  implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
}

Comment: add this in gradel

Comment: ServiceCall.RestApiMultiPartRequests<String> restApiMultiPartRequest = new ServiceCall.RestApiMultiPartRequests<String>(url/*YOUR SERVICE URL*/, hashMap /* HASHMAP OF STRING */, fileparts /*HASH MAP OF FILE AND STRING */, new Response.Listener<String>() {} -> apart from URL part...both hashmap and fileparts aspect is unclear to me. What and how to pass those two arguments w.r.t. the keys I need to pass in the form data as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172021/discussion-between-bodhisatwa-chakraborty-and-jay-thummar).

Comment: Thanks Jay! I just had to change a Lil bit of code in your provided answer and voila! It's done!